# Slick 3.0-RC3 fails with java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException

Tags: scala, concurrency, slick

I'm trying to get familiar with Slick 3.0 and Futures (using Scala 2.11.6). I use simple code based on [Slick's Multi-DB Cake Pattern example](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/slick-multidb-3.0). Why does the following code terminate with an exception and how to fix it?

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.Database
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class Dispatcher(db: Database, dal: DAL) {
  import dal.driver.api._

  def init() = {
    db.run(dal.create)
    try db.run(dal.stuffTable += Stuff(23,"hi"))
    finally db.close

    val x = {
      try db.run(dal.stuffTable.filter(_.serial === 23).result)
      finally db.close
    }
    // This crashes:
    val result = Await.result(x, 2 seconds)
  }
}
```

Execution fails with:

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@5c73f637 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4129c44c[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runSynchronousDatabaseAction(DatabaseComponent.scala:224)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runSynchronousDatabaseAction(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runInContext(DatabaseComponent.scala:201)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runInContext(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.runInternal(DatabaseComponent.scala:75)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.runInternal(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:72)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.run(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
    at Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.scala:15)
    at SlickDemo$.main(SlickDemo.scala:16)
    at SlickDemo.main(SlickDemo.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that something is not correct in what you are trying to do: Slick's `run` method doesn't return `Unit` and doesn't fail with an exception - as it used to in previous versions. `run` now returns a `Future`, so if you want to run actions in sequence you need to `flatMap` the steps, or use a for-comprehension:

```
def init() = {
  val = results for {
    _ <- db.run(dal.create)
    _ <- db.run(dal.stuffTable += Stuff(23, "hi"))
    r <- db.run(dal.stuffTable.filter(_.serial === 23).result)
  } yield r
}
```

I am not sure that you really need to use `db.close` that way: that is actually what may be causing the error (i.e. the db is closed in concurrence with the future that runs the actual queries so the execution can't happen).

If you want to handle errors use `Future`'s capabilities, e.g.:

```
result.onFailure { case NonFatal(ex) => // do something with the exception }
```

Comment: So when db.close should be called?

Comment: You can close the db using the `onComplete` function on the `result` future. Probably that's something that you want to do only when you are shutting down the application though as you don't generally want to create a new connection for each database access you do.

Comment: Yeesh. Why do all the examples, even in the current version, utilize `Await`? Is there a good link or example for how to manage `onFailure()`?