# Slick 3.0 (scala) queries don't return data till they are run multiple times (I think)

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

So I'm very (extremely) new to Databases and slick and scala, so I was using the example code from their documentation at http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html

My problem is that for some reason, I have to run a query multiple times before it returns data. I have to rerun it atleast 3-4 times before it returns results. I use a for-loop to rerun the query and they don't necessarily give me the exact same results each time either.

to create two tables as followed:

```
  class Patients(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, Int, String)](tag, "Patientss") {
    def PID = column[String]("Patient Id", O.PrimaryKey)

    def Gender = column[String]("Gender")

    def Age = column[Int]("Age")

    def Ethnicity = column[String]("Ethnicity")

    def * = (PID, Gender, Age, Ethnicity)
  }

  val patientsss = TableQuery[Patients]

  class DrugEffect(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, String, Double)](tag, "DrugEffectss") {

    def DrugID = column[String]("Drug ID", O.PrimaryKey)

    def PatientID = column[String]("Patient_ID")

    def DrugEffectssss = column[Double]("Drug Effect")

    def * = (DrugID, PatientID, DrugEffectssss)

    def Patient = foreignKey("Patient_FK", PatientID, patientsss)(_.PID)}

 val d_effects = TableQuery[DrugEffect]
```

I then create these tables using

```
  val create_empty = DBIO.seq((patientsss.schema ++ d_effects.schema).create)
  val setup_1 = db.run(create_empty)
```

I have actual data in two text files, which I parse through using a buffered reader.
I store all the Drug ID's in a list creatively named `DrugIds`

Then, I start filling in the tables in the following way

I first fill in the Patients table:

```
   while (switch != 1) {

    val Patient = CurPatient.split("\\s+")

    if (Patient(2).toUpperCase() == "NA" || (Patient(2).toFloat % 1 != 0))
      age = -1
    else age = Patient(2).toInt

    val insertPatient: DBIO[Option[Int]] = patientsss ++= Seq(
      (Patient(0), Patient(1), age, Patient(3))
    )       

    var future = db.run(insertPatient)



    CurPatient = PatientReader.readLine()

    if (CurPatient == null)
      switch = 1 //switch to 1

  }
```

For the DrugEffects table, I do the following:

```
 while (switch != 1) {

    val Effect = CurEffect.split("\\s+")

    for (i <- 1 until DrugIds.size - 1) {
      if (Effect(i).toUpperCase() == "NA")
        d_ef = -1.00

      else d_ef = (Effect(i).toFloat).asInstanceOf[Double]


      val insertEffect: DBIO[Option[Int]] = d_effects ++= Seq(
        (DrugIds(i), Effect(0), d_ef)
      )
      var future2 = db.run(insertEffect)
    }


    CurEffect = EffectReader.readLine()

    if (CurEffect == null)
      switch = 1
  }
```

Then I run a query with the following piece of code

```
val q1 = for {
    c <- patientsss
  } yield (c.PID, c.Gender, c.Age, c.Ethnicity)

  db.stream(q1.result).foreach(println)
```

This should just give me all the data in the Patient's table, but it doesn't necessarily do that.

Sometimes, I get the following error (but not always):

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$3@47089c2c rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6453123[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 215]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2048)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:821)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1372)
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$class.scheduleSynchronousStreaming(DatabaseComponent.scala:253)
at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseDef.scheduleSynchronousStreaming(JdbcBackend.scala:38)
at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$BasicStreamingActionContext.restartStreaming(DatabaseComponent.scala:516)
at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$BasicStreamingActionContext.request(DatabaseComponent.scala:531)
at slick.backend.DatabasePublisher$$anon$3$$anonfun$onNext$2.apply(DatabasePublisher.scala:50)
at slick.backend.DatabasePublisher$$anon$3$$anonfun$onNext$2.apply(DatabasePublisher.scala:49)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.pollAndExecAll(ForkJoinPool.java:1253)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1346)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

If I run a more complex query, the data I get back is accurate to the parameters of the query, but the same problems occur, which is that the results are either duplicated or non-existent or not complete (when I rerun the query multiple times).

Explain like I'm 5 if you can, or point me to a resource that can help me solve these problems

EDIT:

bjfletcher's answer worked (Thanks!), but now I have another problem:

Every now and again, the code will fail with the error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "Patientss" not found; SQL statement:
insert into "Patientss" ("Patient Id","Gender","Age","Ethnicity")  values (?,?,?,?) [42102-162]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4758)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:4736)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:954)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:375)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:279)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:251)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:217)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:415)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:364)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1121)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:71)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:267)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:252)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.prepareStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:386)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$SessionDef$class.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:301)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withPreparedStatement(JdbcBackend.scala:386)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.preparedInsert(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:177)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker$$anonfun$internalInsertAll$1.apply(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:201)
    at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$BaseSession.withTransaction(JdbcBackend.scala:422)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.internalInsertAll(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:198)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.insertAll(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:194)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$InsertInvokerDef$class.$plus$plus$eq(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:73)
    at slick.driver.JdbcInsertInvokerComponent$BaseInsertInvoker.$plus$plus$eq(JdbcInsertInvokerComponent.scala:152)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:459)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$$anonfun$$plus$plus$eq$1.apply(JdbcActionComponent.scala:459)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$$anon$8.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:449)
    at slick.driver.JdbcActionComponent$InsertActionComposerImpl$$anon$8.run(JdbcActionComponent.scala:447)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.liftedTree1$1(DatabaseComponent.scala:231)
    at slick.backend.DatabaseComponent$DatabaseDef$$anon$2.run(DatabaseComponent.scala:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Doesn't happen all the time, but very often, and I have no clue what this means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the DB calls will return to you *immediately* with `Futures`, even if they've not finished with their operations. This is asynchronous not synchronous.

You can change your code to accommodate the `Futures` in one of two ways:

1. you can use `Await.result` with all DB calls, to wait at that point until they complete, for example: `Await.result(db.run(insertEffect), Duration.Inf)`
2. you can use `.map` (or `.flatMap` if you're using another `Future` from within), with code that you want to run when the DB operation is complete. For example: `db.run(insertEffect).map(_ => ... do stuff... )`

Have a look another Stack Overflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897003/slick-3-0-rc3-fails-with-java-util-concurrent-rejectedexecutionexception) regarding the exception with some ideas as to the cause.

Comment: Hey, I just updated the post, do you know what could be cause this error? It only happens if I run the code twice or thrice in a row, with fairly little delay between them

Comment: @S2C It looks like you are trying to run an insert statement before the creation of the table is finished. As bjfletcher said, all db calls run asynchronously in slick. Try to wrap `db.run(create_empty)` in `Await.result`.

Comment: I put my db statements inside awaits which fixed the original problem. I now have a new error which I updated the post with. Also, how would import this database as a class for example or is that not something that can be done

Comment: setup_1.map(_ => your while loop) to block while loop until after DB has been setup. Re imports, look at Slick samples for examples. Any problems, ask a new question on SO rather than changing question in here.