# How would I use slick 3.0 to return one row at a time?

Tags: java, sql, scala, slick, slick-3.0

How I would build a scala query to `return` one row of my table at a time?

My tables are in the following location if they help in answering this question:
[Slick 3.0 (scala) queries don't return data till they are run multiple times (I think)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060458/slick-3-0-scala-queries-dont-return-data-till-they-are-run-multiple-times-i/31061988#31061988)

```
 val q5 = for {
  c <- dat.patientsss 
} yield (c.PID, c.Gender, c.Age, c.Ethnicity)

Await.result((db.stream(q5.result).foreach(println)),Duration.Inf)
```

but instead of printing, I need return each.

Comment: what do you mean by "return each"? Do you mean you want just one row returned from the query?

Comment: yep, just one `(c.PID, c.Gender, c.Age, c.Ethnicity)`  at time

Comment: two ways: 1. add ".take(1)" to "dat.patientsss" line, 2. add ".head" to "q5.result". These will ensure that you get only the first row. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: kind of, except I want to *iterate* through all the rows one by one

Comment: Now I'm curious... Why do you want to iterate over your results having a database roundtrip for each result? Is there a reason not to fetch all rows at once? Since database roundtrips are expensive, you usually want to have as few roundtrips as possible.

Comment: I need to feed data from a text document to a Machine Learning Model. I use a parser to read data and convert it to a database (the database is in memory).  We wanted a database so we can run queries and return customized data (so like age and ethnicity may be a factor into something, but we have the option of returning other stuff besides these or these separately instead of building separate parser for each customized query.  I need to return one row at a time from the query results because the learns one at a time.

Comment: Well then I suggest to go for the solution I posted below. 1. Read all the information from your db, 2. Iterate over the results which will give you each row one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

Use a materialized result instead:

```
val result = Await.result((db.run(q5.result)), Duration.Inf)
```

`result` is a `Seq` that contains all your patient data. Use `foreach` to iterate over the result set:

```
result.foreach(r => yourFancyAlgorithm(r))  // r is a single patients data row
```

---

#### Sidenote

`Await` blocks the current thread making one of slick's best features obsolete. Blocking threads is something you should not do. I highly recommend to read about [`Future` and `Promise`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) in scala.
The above example can be simply written as:

```
val result = db.run(q5.result))
```

`result` in this case will be of type `Future[Seq[(yourPatientsData)]]`. To access the data, use `map` on the result:

```
result.map(d => whatever)  // d is of type Seq[(yourPatientsData)]
```

While waiting for the result, the rest of your application will continue to do its calculations and stuff. Finally when the result is ready, the callback (`d => whatever`) will run.

Comment: I'm not particularly sure how Future would be useful? My algorithm needs the data to do any calculations, so wouldn't I pretty much have to use Await?  Besides that, the suggested code more or less worked (with modifications, ofcourse ;) , It's never that simple, is it?)